# Activities API call not returning correct results

Tags: youtube-data-api

The below api call used to return a feed of results that would have been on my homepage.

`https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?home=true&maxResults=50&part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails&key=AIzaSyC0wL6aecu2rxiTNtW8uvtnb1kx9Kdlb4s`

In the past day or so the feed I get has changed to be only videos from some channel called "Popular on YouTube".

Does anyone know why this API call changed? Is it a bug? Is there a different way to get an authenticated user's activity feed?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the `home` parameter for the `activities` api endpoint has been deprecated.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you must have been using a shared API key.
Either case, "Popular on Youtube" is a Youtube channel by Youtube. Something has broken functionality and I believe it is referrer issue. With that, I suggest getting a new API Key.

You can learn more about and getting a free personal API Key, if you haven't done so.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors